# PHP - Silverstripe - htaccess throwing a 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, silverstripe

I'm jumping into a PHP SilverStripe installation and my local environment handles my .htaccess file fine but my test server is throwing a 500 error on the following. I have no idea what it could be (as I normally roll with ASP.NET). Could you guys help point to me what the potential issues are here?

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
<Files *.ss>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files web.config>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 403 /silverstripe-cache(/|$)
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /thesitename

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* sapphire/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

Comment: Comment line by line and test whether it works. Additionally, have a look at the server logs.

Comment: +1, a 500 error usually leaves something in the logs. If you're on Apache they're in `/var/log/error.log`.

Comment: @Rijk The Apache logs are wherever you have configured them to be. Different linux distros use different locations, and Windows doesn't even have a directory called `/var`. Just because they are there on *your* machine doesn't mean they are there on every installation...

Comment: Is SilverStripe in the same sub folder on your local and test server install? If SilverStripe is installed in the root of the test server you should change "RewriteBase /thesitename" to "RewriteBase /".

Comment: Have a look at your apache configuration (e.g. httpd.conf) if you set `AllowOverride FileInfo` to allow .htaccess changes...

Comment: Thanks so much guys, I'm currently swamped with my day job, so will look at this in the next few days and get back to you, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting out the rewrite base line, or if your test server installation is in a subdirectory, change it to that ;)